# Cancel or postpone the shutdown of the PC

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I know that, since Vista, an application cannot block the shutdown of the PC. All it can do is call the ShutdownBlockReasonCreate fonction which shows that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzwMo.png (now opaque in windows 8)

Since we distribute the PC with the application, is there a parameter that we can change in order to ask the user to save the changes before starting the shutdown process?

My application will run on windows 8 and is in C#.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720587/c-sharp-cancel-windows-shutdown

Comment: You can't, but you can try to save changes when your app is notified of shutdown.

Comment: This is not a duplicate!I know you can't do it by code only. I want to change the settings of the shutdown

Comment: You could deny the user shutdown privilege, and use group policy to prevent the user signing out.  You'd have to provide an alternative method to do so, of course.