# Prevent Windows shutdown when nbackup is backuping database

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I have script which is periodically running nbackup tool for database backup. I noticed that if Windows is restarted when nbackup is running, database ends up in "backup lock" state. Is there any possibility to force Windows to not kill nbackup process?

I noticed that if I run nbackup from WindowsForm application which in FormClosing event prevents Windows shut down, nbackup process finish successfully. But can I rely on observed behavior that processes are stopped/killed in order as they were started?

I would appreciate solution not based on WinForms. Or I would appreciate confirmation that apps are shut down in order of their start. Thus if my guiless process is started from WindowsForms app it will not be killed if WindowsForms app sets Cancel to true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Cancel Windows Shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720587/c-sharp-cancel-windows-shutdown)

Comment: not really duplicated. I would not use WInformApp if possible to prevent windows shutdown. Moreover if I use WinForm app as host for script I need to be sure that process started by this WIndowsApp will not be terminated. This is not about stopping shutdown of WinForm app. This is more about preventing shut down when guiless process is running.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a setting "prevent Windows shutdown while random app X is running", so you either have to code something yourself or live with it. Maybe ask Nbackup for support?

Comment: I don't think you can stop a shutdown, but you can (with work) discover that windows is requesting shutdown and your program can then abort the backup and reset the database state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no really bullet proof solution. The best solution is to allow Windows shutdown normally and recover from terminated backup operation on next Windows start.

This means following on next Windows start: Check whether database is locked as result of terminated backup. If so, unlock database and run backup process again.

This approach has one big advantage - it is working even if there is power cut during backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external application to prevent shutting down while backup is running (instead of doing it by code).

I recommend one of the 4 tools listed here:

[4 Tools to Prevent, Cancel and Abort a Windows System Shutdown or Restart when Applications are Running](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/prevent-cancel-and-abort-a-windows-system-shutdown-or-restart-when-application-is-running/)

I hope it addresses your question.

Comment: Yes, script could start "shut down preventing app" before backup operation and close it after backup operation. However your solution brings 3rd party software dependency I would like to avoid. Still it seems that most promising seems to host script in my own WinForms app as I wrote in my question.