# C# Show messages above logoff screen

Tags: c#, windows

Im trying to make a message showing above the login screen like:

"Goodbye"

But how would this be possible?

I tried disabling the logoff with:

```
Process.Start("shutdown" , "/a");
```

That doesnt work but it does show an error message, above the logoff screen

```
 MessageBox.Show(
 "message",
  "title",
  MessageBoxButtons.OK,
  MessageBoxIcon.Error,
  MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
  (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000);
```

or

```
topmost = true;
```

Does not work either on the logoff screen

How would i show a message above the windows 10 logging of screen?

Or cancel the logging off

Comment: What login screen are you talking about? You mean the Windows login screen?

Comment: Yeah the windows 10 shutting down screen:
http://prntscr.com/atqvhk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Cancel Windows Shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720587/c-sharp-cancel-windows-shutdown)

Comment: @AlexK. They're wanting to show a message when shutting down, not canceling it

Comment: You can specify a background image for the Windows Log-On and Log-Off Screens. Would that help? If cancelling the logging off is preferred then you have the answer for that already.

Comment: @user34660 no, i need an action message but the farrest i got was displaying an error on the shutting down screen (an error would be good enough but i cant specify the text)

Comment: So you want to interrupt a shutdown in order to display a message dialog? Then resume shutdown when its dismissed?

Comment: Perhaps you did not think about my suggestion enough. You could generate an image with a message and then change the background image to that image that will be used for logoff.

Comment: Foud the solution already it was a Policy to enable, somthing like show descriptions on logoff