# Windows 10 shutdown delay, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-10

I want to *delay* windows 10 from shutting down so that my app can finish up some necessary actions like saving data...

Following is a working code example to achieve a delay, however windows cancels the shutdown after about 1 minute of waiting.

How can I achieve a delay without windows aborting the shutdown after a minute? (perhaps it takes 2 or 4 minutes for my app to finish up)

```
Public Class Form1
Declare Function ShutdownBlockReasonCreate Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal reason As String) As Boolean
Declare Function ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef aMessage As Message)
    Const WM_QUERYENDSESSION As Integer = &H11
    Const WM_ENDSESSION As Integer = &H16

    If aMessage.Msg = WM_QUERYENDSESSION OrElse aMessage.Msg = WM_ENDSESSION Then
        ' Block shutdown
        ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(Me.Handle, "Testing 123...")

        ' Do work
        CleanUpAndSave()

        ' Continue with shutdown
        ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(Me.Handle)

        Return
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(aMessage)
End Sub

Private Sub CleanUpAndSave()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch

    ' Pretend work for 3 minutes
    sw.Start()
    Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 180000
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    sw.Stop()
End Sub
```

Please provide working code (if this is at all possible with windows).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one thing you can do is to make your application trigger a shutdown command after finishing the necessary work.

**Update:**

After investigating this, turns out that the `WndProc` method with `ENDSESSION` message gets triggered more than once, causing `CleanUpAndSave()` to also be carried out again. Hence, in addition to the shutdown command, you'll need to add a boolean to check if the message has already been sent from the system to your application.

**The following code was tested and it works just fine on both *Windows 7* and *windows 10*:**

```
Private ShutdownDelayed As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef aMessage As Message)
    Const WM_QUERYENDSESSION As Integer = &H11
    Const WM_ENDSESSION As Integer = &H16

    If aMessage.Msg = WM_QUERYENDSESSION OrElse aMessage.Msg = WM_ENDSESSION Then
        ' Check if the message was sent before and the shutdown command is delayed.
        If ShutdownDelayed Then Exit Sub

        ' Block shutdown
        ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(Me.Handle, "Testing 123...")
        ShutdownDelayed = True

        ' Do work
        CleanUpAndSave()

        ' Continue with shutdown
        ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(Me.Handle)

        ' Do shutdown
        Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0")
        p.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.Start(p)

        ' Exit the application to allow shutdown (For some reason 'ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy'
        '                                         doesn't really unblock the shutdown command).
        Application.Exit()
        Return
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(aMessage)
End Sub
```

**However**, I suggest that you don't suspend the shutdown command and start doing some work immediately without prompting a confirmation message to the user *especially if that work takes several minutes*.

**Instead**, you should display a message box explaining to the user that the application needs to do *some work* before the system shuts down, and let them decide whether to do that work or to shut down immediately. The system will inform the user that your application is preventing it from shutting down. If they care, they will click "Cancel" and read your message. If they don't care, they'll have the option to "Force shutdown" anyway *whether you displayed the message or not*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: If the user ware to change his mind and cancel the shutdown while waiting for my application, or if the user only wanted to logoff, in those cases the PC will still shut down, this would be an annoyance to the user. Any thoughts?

Comment: @stacker, Please read the last 2 paragraphs of my answer. As I stated, you should **not** suspend the shutdown without asking the user (*that* would be annoying to the user, and in many cases, they would *force shutdown* anyway while your program is already processing the work). **You should** leave that decision to the user...

Comment: In that case the user will have to cancel the shutdown anyway to see your message. If they choose `Yes` *do the work/save changes*, then you don't need to shutdown after finishing. If they choose `No`, then you have multiple options here: - Shutdown immediately. - Ask if they want to shutdown/logoff/restart? - etc. I think this is the ideal way to deal with that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot suspend windows shutdown for more than a few seconds: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060216-06/?p=32263

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this article is, but I just tested the OP's code on Windows 7 and Windows 10. I managed to suspend shutdown for "more than a few seconds" unlike what the article claims! On Win7, it just displays a *"This program is preventing Windows from shutting down"*  message after a while, and on Win10, it simply cancels the shutdown command after almost a minute as the OP stated. Any other resources to backup that claim or to clear this conflict? Thank you.

Comment: Well, after some research, turns out that what's no longer allowed since Windows Vista is the *Silent shutdown cancellations* which I suppose is what the article is talking about. However blocking shutdown is still possible using the "*New API for proactively registering shutdown objections*" `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` which can't be done silently (the system will give a choice to either wait or shutdown anyway). More info [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17720935/4934172).