# When does 'e.Cancel = true' in FormClosing NOT prevent logoff?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Winforms app that minimizes to the Taskbar when a user clicks on the X. It does not prevent a user from logging off.

On the other hand, I have an app that shows a dialog when a user clicks the X, and it *does* prevent logging off showing:

> "This app is preventing you from signing out."

I've tried tracking down what exactly is the difference between them but haven't found the difference. I thought it would be the dialog, but a test app has shown that in any case that the app sets `e.Cancel = true;` in `FormClosing` - the test app prevents logoff. This doesn't matter if the app shows a dialog or not, and if `ShowInTaskbar` is true or false. And both apps and the test app only `Cancel` if `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing`.

So basically what I'm asking is when does `e.Cancel = true` **not** prevent logging off?

Comment: Does the app that minimizes check `CloseReason` in it's event handler?

Comment: @gnud Yes. Both Cancel only if `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing`. Thanks. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Not sure I understood your problem correctly, but when you use the X to close the form, `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing`, hecne, `e.cancel = true;` is called. However, if the app is closed while shutting down/loggin off, `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`, and hence, `e.cancel = true;` doesn't get called.

Comment: @ispiro, Nope, Logging-off /signing-out **is** `CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`. I just double-checked it on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks. Now it seems you're right. I'm checking why my test app was preventing shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This doesn't matter if the app shows a dialog or not... And both apps and the test app only Cancel if `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing`

That's the whole point, it doesn't matter whether you show a dialog or not. In the first app, you're ***not*** calling `e.Cancel == true;` at all because `e.CloseReason` is not `UserClosing`, it is `WindowsShutDown`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason):

> **UserClosing**
>
> The user is closing the form through the user interface (UI), for
>   example by clicking the **Close** button on the form window, selecting
>   **Close** from the window's control menu, or pressing ALT+F4.

You can confirm that it *is* in fact `WindowsShutDown`, by running some simple test like the following:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\SomePath\CloseReason.txt", e.CloseReason.ToString());
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) e.Cancel = true;
}
```

If you want to prevent the shutdown/log-off, you can either set `e.Cancel` to `true` without a condition, or by checking if `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Cancel = true;

    // Or..

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing || 
        e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But, please use this responsibly and be aware that the user can always force the shutdown/log-off as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541245/4934172).

---

**Edit:**

If, on the other hand, you have some logic which might prevent the form from closing (i.e., by calling `e.Cancel = true;`) and you don't want that logic to apply when shutting down (or logging off), I always use something like the following:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return; // Go ahead and close.

    if (!SafeToClose())
    {
        // Optional:
        if (MessageBox.Show("Important process is running. Stay?",...) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        // Or directly:
        //e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You got me on the right track for this point. My test app only blocks when executed from Visual Studio. When the exe is executed by itself, it doesn't. So it seems like the problem is Visual Studio. Now I need to check whether the actual offending app is the same.

Comment: OK. It seems like that was the problem. The app does _not_ seem to prevent shutdown when executed from the exe, only when executed from within Visual Studio. In  fact, though the text was of the app, I think it's not the app at all that's causing the problem, it's Visual Studio.

Comment: @ispiro I updated the answer. Whether executed from the exe or using VS, calling `e.Cancel = true;` **should actually** prevent the system from shutting down _at least for a few seconds_  and display a warning message. Whatever happens next is up to the user _and the system_ because the behavior differs between Win7 and Win10. Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538592/windows-10-shutdown-delay-vb-net/41541245#comment70287967_41541084) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. My problem was actually that I was afraid the app will annoy users when logging off. I wanted to make sure it detects a logoff and closes.

Comment: @ispiro, Not sure if that's what you mean, but I added another paragraph to my answer.

Comment: Yes. That's similar to what I have. But when testing, logoff what still being prevented. The reason was that Visual Studio apparently was preventing it, though showing the same text as on my app, so I thought it was the app itself preventing the logoff.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Yes, VS will probably prevent/delay the shutdown/log-off process on its own. That has nothing to do with the program being debugged.