# Suspend Windows Shutdown until application finished it´s work VB.Net

Tags: windows, vb.net, delay, shutdown

i wrote a little desktop utility which automatically detects an USB Stick which contains updates for antivirus patterns and software packages. It can either perform those updates on detection or on system shutdown/restart and here comes the problem...
I am not able to get the suspended shutdown to work properly..
If i am using this code my application sucessfully blocks the windows shutdown, but won´t perform the updating process.

```
    ' >>>>Process Windows Shutdown<<<<
    If m.Msg = WM_QUERYENDSESSION OrElse m.Msg = WM_ENDSESSION Then

        ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(Me.Handle, "Performing #### and Kasperksy Updates...")
        UnZipKit()
        ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(Me.Handle)
        Return

    End If
```

I already found out that i need to return FALSE somewhere, but i can´t figure out how. The Microsoft statement can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms700677(v=vs.85)

As for additional information, if i won´t include the RETURN windows shutdown won´t be delayed what so ever...

Comment: You should read the following thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538592/windows-10-shutdown-delay-vb-net

Comment: I already did, but the code used had the same problem like mine. The function does not proceed while in the windows shutdown screen.

Comment: @Stormface16 Please read the last two paragraph in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541245/4934172) to that question.

Comment: As stated above i already read the article. It says : "Again, note that this API does not replace the need to return FALSE (or delay responding) to WM_QUERYENDSESSION to block shutdown. Applications need to do this in addition to using the API."

Comment: @Stormface16 I asked you to read the last two paragraphs in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541245/4934172) which tells you exactly what you should do. Did you do that? Moreover, if you insist on executing some code immediately after preventing the shutdown without waiting for user input first, then your program should _still_ run perfectly fine while in the "shutdown screen". Did you try the code in the answer?

Comment: If your app needs to perform some actions before the System shuts down, you just need to set `msg.Result = IntPtr.Zero` when you receive a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message. This will cause the System to show the RestartManager's ShutDown Suspended message. The reason why you application is blocking the Shutdown Proc is set using `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`, which just creates the string message. Do not block on `WM_ENDSESSION` (i.e., just `If m.Msg = WM_QUERYENDSESSION then (...)`). In the `WM_ENDSESSION` handler, call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy` if you created a block reason. That's all

Comment: [Restart Manager - Guidelines for Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/RstMgr/guidelines-for-applications) -- Of course the user can force the shutdown. You should be prepared for that, too. If this procedure takes time (more than 20 seconds), I suggest you find another way/another time to backup your stuff. Usually, this is a scheduled task that is performed in a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, but i´m not really sure how to integrate the msg.result = IntPtr.Zero  - the updating process  itself only lasts for about 20secs or so and all the operators are trained before the Programm is used. So the force shutdown is no problem. I just need help to integrate it :)

Comment: That's a (copy/paste) typo `m.result = IntPtr.Zero`. This is the standard way to set the application's response to a Windows message. Each message has specific responses that have spcific meaning. In a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero` means that the application is not ready to terminate. The reason is displayed to the User, passing a description (`string`) to `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`. When your app is ready to close, it can just call `Application.Exit()`. The System will then proceed to shutdown immediately.

Comment: @Jimi My Code works until a certain point... Is it even possible to perform a process.start when windows is trying to shut down ? I want to perform a silent install of a .exe installer. Is this the problem?

Comment: I linked that document for a reason. See the section [Using Restart Manager with a Primary Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/RstMgr/using-restart-manager-with-a-primary-installer) and the following docs about a Secondary Installer.

Comment: @Jimi I am really sorry to annoy you stuff, that´s probably extremely easy for you, but i can´t really figure out how to integrate it into my existing code, because i am not familiar with C++ at all

Comment: You have to schedule the installer in the next session. Sorry, but I can't write a tutorial in the comments section. You'll have to research/try it out and post a specific question if something doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach is to write a shutdown script.
Like here described https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd630947(v=msdn.10)

a vbs script can do almost anything analogue to vb net-